# Bugs Weka 3.8.6

Tags: weka

After loading a dataset diabetes.arff and then choosing a classifier such as J48, I can start one test and after that the button "start" becomes disabled. Even clicking on stop it continues disabled. I changed the classifier to ZeroR and then the button became enabled again, but it does not work.I clicked several times and nothing. I also reinstalled Weka and tried other datasets, but every time the same problem.

I recorded a video to show this bug on https://1drv.ms/v/s!ApZk5TJm2dA3odp28KVQSssv34Lu4Q?e=uyrTD7

Comment: Do you have the same problem with 3.8.5?

Comment: Yes, I do...now. Before installing the version 3.8.6 the previous version was working fine.

Comment: Just downloaded the [zip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/weka/files/weka-3-8/3.8.6/weka-3-8-6.zip/download) file of Weka 3.8.6 and it works fine (executed command `java -jar weka.jar` from terminal in directory containing `weka.jar`). I'm on Linux, so I manage my own Java installation. Do you have a separate Java installation? What do you get when you run `java -version` in a terminal?

Comment: I'm on Windows...I have this version of java: version "1.8.0_321"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_321-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.321-b07, mixed mode)

Comment: I uninstalled both version of Weka and also Java and then installed Weka 3.8.5 and Java. Same problem. I run windows 64 bits and as Weka is 32 bits I installed Java 32 bits as well. Same problem...Have you seen the video where the button "start" stays disabled after being clicked? What am I missing?

Comment: Java code and therefore Weka is not limited to 32bit. You can run it with 32bit and 64bit JVMs. The installer may be 32bits. I haven't used 32bit JVMs for at least 10 years. I've never come across the problem with the start button that you've encountered in your video. Here's what I would do: open a command-prompt, navigate to the directory that contains the `weka.jar`, determine the full path to the `java` executable that comes with your 1.8.0_321-b07 Java installation and execute the following command (using the correct java path): `"C:\Program files\...\java" -jar weka.jar`

Comment: I did that and nothing changed. Same problem with the button and also not running a selected classifier even when I choose different options. I also tried installing on my other notebook and the problem is the same. Do you think it can be a problem with Windows?

Comment: When running in from the terminal/command-prompt, did you get any error output?

Comment: Open Weka with console I get this messages...Environment variable 'JAVA_OPTS' does not exist!
Environment variable 'CLASSPATH' does not exist!
WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by weka.gui.GUIChooserApp (file:/C:/Program%20Files/Weka-3-8-6/weka.jar)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of weka.gui.GUIChooserApp
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release

Comment: All these are fine, see Eibe's [post on the Wekalist](https://list.waikato.ac.nz/hyperkitty/list/wekalist@list.waikato.ac.nz/message/3N5CLBOAKXZ2AZH76VLLVX3KUO7ZU3WM/).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could try the *Weka Investigator*, a more powerful tool than the Weka Explorer. The Investigator is part of the ADAMS framework. For your purposes, you can download the *adams-ml-app* snapshot from the [snapshot download page](https://adams.cms.waikato.ac.nz/download/snapshot/)

Have a look at the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d5e5dknWSJw) of my talk from the [Weka User Conference 2021](https://events.waikato.ac.nz/events/2021-international-weka-user-conference/), for an introduction to the tool.